# error copying image prestashop 1.6 csv import

Tags: php, csv, import, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to upload products in Prestashop 1.6 through CSV Import, but it shows

> error copying image Prestashop 1.6 CSV import.

I found that `return @copy($source, $destination)` in `tools.php` is not working but I don't know why.

Comment: You tried to restore files and folders privilege ?

Comment: Have you gave a correct url of the images?

Comment: @MatteoEnna I have not done anything with folder privilege.

Comment: @sarcom yes the URLs are correct

Comment: Are you using the PrestaShop core import functionality?

Comment: @sarcom yeah, I'm trying to upload products through Prestashop BO Csv Import, but it throws an error: error copying image ,i tried to sort it out and found @copy($source, $destination) in tools.php is not working.I don't know the reason behind it, please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told by @Matteo Enna, you have check the privileges rules of `psroot/img/` and `psroot/img/p/` folders, 0755 for the folders and 0644 for the files, but check also the owner because this problem remains if you have a wrong hosting configuration, the core import of PS1.6 it's very good, probably there is a problem with the folders (permissions and owner) or to retrieve/download the images from the web.

Comment: its working fine when i take images from other websites but when i try to use images from say 'joke.biz/image/abc.jpg' where as my own site is joke.com. I checked the privileges of both sites, that is fine

Answer (score -1):

Check your PHP default type on your server. I found that if you have a PHP version lower than 7 you will get the upload error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Not sure what you mean by "PHP default type" - maybe you can clarify this to make your answer more useful?